Currently stuck with an ea in mt5
i am trying to code an ea that opens postitions based on an account being in profit,as long as the trades open are in profit,it opens maximum possible positions,i does not open a position if the positions are in loss or negative
, code is not executing anything, gives me 0 erros, 1 warning implicit conversion from 'number' to 'string' testing.mq5 87  26
input double initialLotSize = 0.1; // Initial lot size
input int maxPositions = 100; // Maximum number of positions allowed
input double pipValue = 0.0001; // Pip value for the currency pair

double initialPrice = 0.0; // Price of the manually opened position
bool manualPositionOpened = false; // Flag to indicate if the manual position is opened
int totalPositions = 0; // Total number of positions

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   // Initialization code here
   return INIT_SUCCEEDED;
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
   // Cleanup code here
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate leverage based on account balance and margin           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double CalculateLeverage()
{
   double accountBalance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE);
   double accountMargin = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_MARGIN);

   if (accountMargin == 0.0)
      return 0.0; // To avoid division by zero

   return accountBalance / accountMargin;
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Check if leverage allows opening new positions                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool CanOpenPositions()
{
   double leverage = CalculateLeverage();
   return leverage > 1.0; // Allow opening positions if leverage is greater than 1
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Check if price moves 20 pips from the initial price             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool PriceMoved20Pips()
{
   if (!manualPositionOpened)
      return false; // No manual position opened yet

   double currentPrice = SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID);
   return MathAbs(currentPrice - initialPrice) >= 20 * pipValue; // Check if price moves 20 pips
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Open new positions based on criteria                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OpenNewPositions()
{
   // Check if there are any closed positions
   if (PositionsTotal() < totalPositions) {
      // If a position is closed, reset the flag
      manualPositionOpened = false;
   }

   // Update the totalPositions variable
   totalPositions = PositionsTotal();

   // Check if there are any open positions
   if (totalPositions == 0) {
      // If there are no open positions, reset the initial price and manualPositionOpened flag
      initialPrice = 0.0;
      manualPositionOpened = false;
      return;
   }

   // Calculate the total profit of all open positions
   double totalProfit = 0.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < totalPositions; ++i) {
      if (PositionSelect(i)) {
         totalProfit += PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PROFIT);
      }
   }

   // If total profit is negative or a manual position is not opened, do not open new positions
   if (totalProfit < 0 || !manualPositionOpened) {
      return;
   }

   // If a manual position is opened, update the initial price
   if (totalProfit > 0 && !manualPositionOpened) {
      initialPrice = SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID);
      manualPositionOpened = true;
   }

   // Check if leverage allows opening new positions and if price hasn't moved 20 pips
   if (!CanOpenPositions() || PriceMoved20Pips()) {
      return;
   }

   // Calculate maximum number of positions based on leverage and balance
   int maxAllowedPositions = maxPositions - totalPositions;

   // Open new positions
   double lotSize = initialLotSize;
   for (int i = 0; i < maxAllowedPositions; ++i) {
      // Prepare request
      MqlTradeRequest request;
      ZeroMemory(request);
      request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;
      request.type = ORDER_TYPE_BUY;
      request.symbol = Symbol();
      request.volume = lotSize;
      request.price = SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK);

      // Send request
      MqlTradeResult result;
      if (!OrderSend(request, result)) {
         Print("Error opening order: ", GetLastError());
      }
   }
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   // Check account balance and leverage
   double accountBalance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE);
   double leverage = CalculateLeverage();

   // Calculate maximum number of positions based on leverage and balance
   int maxAllowedPositions = (int)(accountBalance / initialLotSize / leverage);

  // Print account information
Print("Account Balance: " + DoubleToString(accountBalance));
Print("Leverage: " + DoubleToString(leverage));
Print("Max Allowed Positions: " + IntegerToString(maxAllowedPositions));


   // Open new positions based on criteria
   OpenNewPositions();
}


there is nothing to execute in the code you posted. It needs a main. And what about the warning? Why not fix it?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'd guess that's because this isn't really c++ it's some c++ like dialect used by metatrader

@AlanBirtles yes after reading more carefully I came to that conclusion, but then still there must be steps to take before something can be executed (though they might be obvious to someone familiar with the md5)

its meta trader 5

I think your
void OpenNewPositions()
{...}

returns too easily if there are no open positions:
if (totalPositions == 0) {
   ...      
   return;
  }

Or when there is some leverage problem:
// Check if leverage allows opening new positions and if price hasn't moved 20 pips
if (!CanOpenPositions() || PriceMoved20Pips()) {
   return;
  }

Or even otherwise.
I would examine this by adding some Print() instruction right before return; is called. Then you'ld know where your code bounces.
